# How exactly do I generate the View Matrix from a camera position and orientation?

Tags: c++, shader, quaternions, glm-math

I have a camera and it has a position and a quaternion and I have been trying to generate a View matrix from that.

I have tried

```
auto camera_rotation = glm::mat4_cast(camera.orientation);
auto camera_translation = glm::translate(glm::mat4(), camera.position);
auto viewMatrix = glm::inverse(camera_translation * camera_rotation);
```

Then I tried doing

```
auto camera_dir = camera.position +  glm::rotate(camera.orientation, glm::vec3(1, 0, 0));
auto camera_up = glm::rotate(camera.orientation, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
auto viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(camera.position, camera_dir, camera_up);
```

but the camera_up is not always correct.

If I manually set the ViewMatrix to

```
glm::lookAt(camera.position, glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
```

Then I see what I expect to see, so I think the rest of my calculations are correct.

How do I do this properly?

Comment: At start you should define your transfromations. 

camera_rotation - rotates points from world CS to Camera CS or From Camera to World? 

Than define the order of transformations. It translate first than rotate ? 
transform  = camera_translation * camera_rotation or
transform  = camera_rotation * camera_translation. 

Than you can build camera Extrinsic matrix (transform from World to Camera) and multiply with camera Intrinsic matrix (the focal length  and more)

Comment: Camera position is the camera position in the world. I am using the Model-View-Projection Matrix to transform the vertices, so what I believe the intrinsic matrix is is described by the Projection matrix.

Comment: It appears the second version is correct, but I was seeing it wrong due to my compiler ignoring changes in header files when building. Does anybody know why the first version is incorrect?